# Mazimizing Width in the Adaptation Wordpress Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, media-queries, viewport

I'm having a few problems with the *Adaptation* theme for Wordpress. I installed it and optimized my blog design, and it looks amazing on mobile and tablets, but I can't **stretch it** to fill the whole viewport on larger desktops.

*EDIT: The link provided below no longer works, but the original *body{width:}* was incorrectly set to 90%*

[Here's my blog](http://nanopassio.es), see what I mean? The *#secondary* sidebar just doesn't go all the way to the right. I've tried floating it, making the *#main* section go larger, (which I couldn't achieve), playing with media queries, but nothing seems to work.

My objective is to make the whole webpage a little **less cluttered**. Everything seems to be floated left, and it would't be a problem if it wasn't for that little sidebar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
body.secondary-sidebar #page 
{
    width: 90%;
}
```

to

```
body.secondary-sidebar #page 
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

should work, you might need to adjust some of the widths etc with that change.

Comment: Immediate fix! Thank you! :)